# Running into "Maximum call stack" errors on a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm making a height map editor. Basically its a grid of numbers where you can change any location by +/- 1. The editor then makes sure that there can only be a difference of 1 between any of the touching 8 tiles.

I'm doing this with a recursive function. Basically its looking at it's 8 neighbors and adjusting them as needed. If any where adjusted, call the function on all 8 neighbors.

I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` errors after messing around for awhile and I can't see where they are coming from. I'm doing checks to make sure I don't try to access non-exsiting grid locations...

The function is this:

```
var moveDown = function (x, y) {
    var updated = false;
    if (x-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }

    if (updated) {
        if (x-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x-1, y); }
        if (x+1 < size) { moveDown(x+1, y); }
        if (y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x, y-1); }
        if (y+1 < size) { moveDown(x, y+1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x-1, y-1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size) { moveDown(x-1, y+1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x+1, y-1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size) { moveDown(x+1, y+1); }
    }
}
```

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/wt7m3hs5/). And it looks like I can just inline it, so I did that too.

```js
var size = 15
var grid;
var active = {x: -1, y: -1};

var moveDown = function (x, y) {
    var updated = false;
    if (x-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    
    if (updated) {
        if (x-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x-1, y); }
        if (x+1 < size) { moveDown(x+1, y); }
        if (y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x, y-1); }
        if (y+1 < size) { moveDown(x, y+1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x-1, y-1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size) { moveDown(x-1, y+1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x+1, y-1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size) { moveDown(x+1, y+1); }
    }
}



var moveUp = function (x, y) {
    var updated = false;
    if (x-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y-1] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y+1] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y-1] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y+1] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y-1] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y+1] += 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    
    if (updated) {
        if (x-1 >= 0) { moveUp(x-1, y); }
        if (x+1 < size) { moveUp(x+1, y); }
        if (y-1 >= 0) { moveUp(x, y-1); }
        if (y+1 < size) { moveUp(x, y+1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0) { moveUp(x-1, y-1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size) { moveUp(x-1, y+1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0) { moveUp(x+1, y-1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size) { moveUp(x+1, y+1); }
    }
}



var init = function () {
    $('#board').mouseleave(function () {
        active.x = -1;
        active.y = -1;
    })
    .mousemove(function () {
        active.x = -1;
        active.y = -1;
    });
    $('#reset').click(function () {
        for(var x=0; x<size; x++) {
            for(var y=0; y<size; y++) {
                grid[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    $(window).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 119 || e.keyCode === 87) {
            // W
            grid[active.x][active.y] += 1;
            moveUp(active.x, active.y);
        }
        if (e.keyCode === 115 || e.keyCode === 83) {
            // S
            grid[active.x][active.y] -= 1;
            moveDown(active.x, active.y);
        }
    });
    
    grid = [];
    for(var x=0; x<size; x++) {
        grid[x] = [];
        var row = $('<div class="row">');
        for(var y=0; y<size; y++) {
            grid[x][y] = 1;
            var cell = $('<div id="C' + x + '_' + y + '" class="cell">');
            cell.data('x', x).data('y', y);
            cell.mousemove(function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                active.x = $this.data('x');
                active.y = $this.data('y');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            row.append(cell)
        }
        $('#board').append(row);
    }
    
    setInterval(function () {
        for(var x=0; x<size; x++) {
            for(var y=0; y<size; y++) {
                $('#C' + x + '_' + y).text(grid[x][y]);
            }
        }
        $('#info').text('x: ' + active.x + ' y: ' + active.y);
    }, 100);
};
init();
```

```css
#board {
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.row {
    height: 25px;
}

.cell {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<p>
    Click on the board once to set focus. This lets the keyboard work. Press <strong>S</strong> to make a tile go down, press <strong>W</strong> to make a tile go up.
</p>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: What was wrong with the old "stack overflow" error message?? :)

Comment: In `update` is true it will call moveDown again (adding (push) to the call stack, and since the function doesn't return there is no "pop" of the stack). If update is true every time the stack will eventually overflow causing the error. You should separate these two steps to avoid recursivness

Comment: Your problem is that you only have one `updated` variable. It is set to true when *any* of the neighbors was updated, but then causes *all* neighbors to be checked again (which is unnecessary). Try using a queue instead, and have a look at the [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` This error occurs when there is no breakpoint for recursion function. When you call any function from that function or such like that. Then the execution goes then caller function goes into stack and callee function gets into memory for execution. If there is no return statement or condition before recursion, then processor stack gets full and throws this error message.

In your case, you are calling `moveDown` from `moveDown` but there one condition which is always true and which is responsible for calling `moveDown` again, or same with `moveUp`.

Just debug with breakpoints, you will get where it is wrong.

Comment: I can prove you that the recursion in the OPs code always terminates if you want (his condition is `if (updated)` if you want to have a closer look). However, maybe you can suggest a better algorithm?

Comment: I had an invalid conditional check in the 2nd if. The `x-1` should have been a `x+1`.